# how could I delete archived messages partially or completely from ejabberd server 16.06

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

how could I delete archived messages partially or completely from ejabberd server 16.06 (I am using conversejs as ejaberd client).

Comment: Check out http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#manage-remove. You might even have to write your own js method to support the functionality,

Answer (score 2):

To remove a single [collection](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#collections). You need to send a request to the ejabberd server in below format.

```
<iq type='set' id='remove1'>
  <remove xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
          with='juliet@capulet.com/chamber'
          start='1469-07-21T02:56:15Z'/>
</iq>
```

**with:** The 'with' attribute MAY specify JID of XMPP entities
**start:** 'start' and 'end' elements MAY be specified to indicate a date range

Yes there might be an end attribute. You can read all about in details [here](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#manage-remove). Perhaps you might have to implement the api by yourself at client side.

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with converse.js

Comment: Note that the single collection docs in the link has been deprecated. Consider using [XEP-0313](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) section `3.2 Message retention and deletion` (still experimental).